# Remove parentheses and text within from strings in R

Tags: r, regex

In R, I have a list of companies such as:

```
companies  <-  data.frame(Name=c("Company A Inc (COMPA)","Company B (BEELINE)", "Company C Inc. (Coco)", "Company D Inc.", "Company E"))
```

I want to remove the text with parenthesis, ending up with the following list:

```
                  Name
1        Company A Inc 
2            Company B
3       Company C Inc.
4       Company D Inc.
5            Company E
```

One approach I tried was to split the string and then use ldply:

```
companies$Name <- as.character(companies$Name)
c<-strsplit(companies$Name, "\\(")
ldply(c)
```

But because not all company names have parentheses portions, it fails:

```
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths
```

I'm not married to the strsplit solution. Whatever removes that text and the parentheses would be fine.

Comment: Also see `bracketX` in the `qdap` package.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

A `gsub` should work here

```
gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(companies$Name))
# or using "raw" strings as of R 4.0
gsub(r"{\s*\([^\)]+\)}","",as.character(companies$Name))

# [1] "Company A Inc"  "Company B"      "Company C Inc."
# [4] "Company D Inc." "Company E"
```

Here we just replace occurrences of "(...)" with nothing (also removing any leading space). R makes it look worse than it is with all the escaping we have to do for the parenthesis since they are special characters in regular expressions.

Comment: Why did you use `[^\\)]+` between the parentheses?

Comment: @rrs I wanted to match all non closing parenthesis characters. I think a non-greedy `.*?` would work as well but if I know the only thing that can end my match block I like to use that explicitly.

Comment: **NOTE**: To make sure only those parentheses that are at the end of string are removed, use `gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)\\s*$","",as.character(companies$Name))`

Answer (score 24):

You could use `stringr::str_replace`.  It's nice because it accepts factor variables.

```
companies <- data.frame(Name=c("Company A Inc (COMPA)","Company B (BEELINE)", 
                               "Company C Inc. (Coco)", "Company D Inc.", 
                               "Company E"))

library(stringr)
str_replace(companies$Name, " \\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", "")
# [1] "Company A Inc"  "Company B"      "Company C Inc." 
# [4] "Company D Inc." "Company E"
```

And if you still want to use `strsplit`,  you could do

```
companies$Name <- as.character(companies$Name)
unlist(strsplit(companies$Name, " \\(.*\\)"))
# [1] "Company A Inc"  "Company B"      "Company C Inc."
# [4] "Company D Inc." "Company E"
```

Comment: same idea using `stringi`: `stringi::stri_replace(companies$Name, regex = " \\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", "")`

Comment: just to make it a bit shorter, `str_remove(companies$Name, " \\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)")`

Answer (score 10):

You could also use:

```
library(qdap)
companies$Name <-  genX(companies$Name, " (", ")")

companies
        Name
1  Company A Inc
2       CompanyB
3 Company C Inc.
4 Company D Inc.
5       CompanyE
```

Comment: This code does not leave any space after value in () is removed. May I know if you have any solution for that? I'd like to leave single space

Comment: @ZahraHnn  If you check the code it is `" ("`  Try with `"("`  Not sure about your case though without a reproducible example

Comment: that won't work, actually I want to remove emojis which are like <f0><ed><f8>; using: genX(mytext$text, "<", ">"),  in cases which there's no space between text and emoji, the result will be unsatisfactory. eg,considering this text "I  was so<f0><ed><f8>to see you<f0><ee><ed>" , the user used emoji with no space and when I removed the <><><> results is like "... soto see …" , but I was expecting "... so to see … "

Answer (score 8):

If the parentheses are paired and balanced, you can use

```r
gsub("\\s*(\\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*\\))", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/QUDjdY/1) and [R demo online](https://ideone.com/y1XQ8z):

```r
companies  <-  data.frame(Name=c("Company A Inc (COMPA)","Company B (BEELINE)", "Company C Inc. (Coco)", "Company D Inc.", "Company E"))
gsub("\\s*(\\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*\\))", "", companies$Name, perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```r
[1] "Company A Inc"  "Company B"      "Company C Inc." "Company D Inc."
[5] "Company E"
```

**Regex details**

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*\))` - Capturing group 1 (required to recurse the pattern part between parentheses):

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*`  - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `(?:(?1)[^()]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of the whole Group 1 pattern (`(?1)` is a regex subroutine recursing Group 1 pattern) and then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 5):

In your case it will come to the desired result, wenn you remove everything starting with  `(`.

```
sub(" \\(.*", "", companies$Name)
#[1] "Company A Inc"  "Company B"      "Company C Inc." "Company D Inc." "Company E"
```

To *remove parentheses and text within from a strings* you can use.

```
sub("\\(.*)", "", c("ab (cd) ef", "(ij) kl"))
#[1] "ab  ef" " kl"
```

If there are more than one parentheses:

```
gsub("\\(.*?)", "", c("ab (cd) ef (gh)", "(ij) kl"))
#[1] "ab  ef " " kl"
```

`(` needs to be escaped `\\(`, `.` means everything, `*` means repeated 0 to n, `?` means non greedy to remove not everything from the first to the last match.

As an alternative you can use `[^)]` what means everything but not a `)`.

```
sub("\\([^)]*)", "", c("ab (cd) ef", "(ij) kl"))
#[1] "ab  ef" " kl"   

gsub("\\([^)]*)", "", c("ab (cd) ef (gh)", "(ij) kl"))
#[1] "ab  ef " " kl"
```

If there are *nested* parentheses:

```
gsub("\\(([^()]|(?R))*\\)", "", c("ab ((cd) ef) gh (ij)", "(ij) kl"), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "ab  gh " " kl"
```

Where `a(?R)z` is a recursion which match one or more letters `a` followed by exactly the same number of letters `z`.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(qdap)
bracketX(companies$Name) -> companies$Name
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: bracketX - Apply bracket removal to character vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Another `gsub` solution: replace the term in the parens preceded by an optional space by `""`, i.e. empty string

```
gsub("(\\s*\\(\\w+\\))", "", companies$Name)

[1] "Company A Inc"  "Company B"      "Company C Inc." "Company D Inc."
[5] "Company E"
```