# Remove a string except words in specific position in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have the following strings

```
string <- c("Trade (% of GDP) – Latin America & Caribbean (WB/WDI/NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS-ZJ)", "Trade (% of GDP) – North America (WB/WDI/NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS-XU)"  )
```

In this string, I want to remove everything except the ``middle" sentence.

My expected result should look like this:

```
excpected_string <- c("Latin America & Caribbean", "North America"  )
```

Can someone help me how I can do this using `gsub`

Comment: I think what you are looking for might be regular expressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove parentheses and text within from strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173194/remove-parentheses-and-text-within-from-strings-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression. Based on the two examples, the two patterns I identified were 1) remove everything before `-`, and 2) remove everything within parens `()`.

Here's one solution to do that:

```r
string <- c("Trade (% of GDP) – Latin America & Caribbean (WB/WDI/NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS-ZJ)", "Trade (% of GDP) – North America (WB/WDI/NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS-XU)"  )
gsub("^.*\\s–\\s|\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", "", string)
#> [1] "Latin America & Caribbean" "North America"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The first part of the regex `^.*\\s–\\s` says "grab all the characters from the start of the string before we find `-`".

In regex, the `|` means OR, so the second regex `\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\` identifies all text (and leading / trailing spaces) inside parens. Credit [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173194/remove-parentheses-and-text-within-from-strings-in-r) for that regex.

Comment: For some unknown to me reason, I re-run the code today and the string ´Trade` Didn’t go. I tried to see if there were any unintentional changes in my code, and I found none. Do you think think problem has to do with R?

Comment: @msh855 - very unlikely anything would have corrupted within R itself (as in I've used R for 10+ years and never experienced anything like that). Did your input `string` change? It's more probable that the format of `string` changed and the regex is no longer capturing the parts of the string. Can you re-upload `string`?

Answer (score 1):

Another idea

```
trimws(sub(".*–([^\\(]+).*", "\\1", string))
# [1] "Latin America & Caribbean" "North America"
```

Removes everything up to and including `–` as well as what follows an opening bracket `(`. We use a capture group to isolate the desired output. `trimws` removes leading and trailing whitespaces.