# by removing all texts inside parentheses

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string which I would like to remove the parentheses and the text within from. I do not understand regex so is there another method to remove it. I want to use R to do this

Code:
`Objects <- "Wood (Brown), leaves (Green), Sky (Blue)"`

End Result:
`Objects <- "Wood, leaves, Sky"`

Comment: relevant (possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173194/remove-parentheses-and-text-within-from-strings-in-r

Comment: Hi Sotos, I did see this but I could not understand the solution :)

Comment: Hi. Yes, It is slightly overfitted to that specific usecase (at least the accepted answer). That's why I didn't close the question and just left it as a comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove parentheses and text within from strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173194/remove-parentheses-and-text-within-from-strings-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `gsub` here for a base R option:

```
Objects <- "Wood (Brown), leaves (Green), Sky (Blue)"
gsub("\\s*\\(.*?\\)\\s*", "", Objects)

[1] "Wood, leaves, Sky"
```

Here is the regex pattern being used, followed by an explanation:

```
\s*\(.*?\)\s*

\s*   match (optional) whitespace before the opening (
\(    match a literal (
.*?   match all content inside the (...)
\)    match a literal (
\s*   match (optional) whitespace after the closing )
```

Note that we use `\s*` on both sides of the pattern, to also capture and remove any unwanted whitespace which might be left over after the replacement.

Comment: Hi Tim, could you explain what this means "\\s*\\(.*?\\)\\s*"

Comment: Sure, I will add an explanation.

Comment: Wow Tim you made it so simple for me to understand! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Base R solution using `strsplit()`

```
s <- paste0(unlist(strsplit(Objects,split = "\\s\\(.*?\\)")),collapse = "")
```

or

```
s <- paste0(trimws(unlist(strsplit(Objects,split = "\\(.*?\\)"))),collapse = "")
```

such that

```
> s
[1] "Wood, leaves, Sky"
```