# In R, how can I extract all the text up to the left parenthesis?

Tags: r, string, replace, stringr

In the Winner column of my dataframe, I want to remove all the text starting from the left parenthesis.

Searching stackoverflow.com, I found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173194/remove-parentheses-and-text-within-from-strings-in-r), and I applied its stringr solution in my code, but it does not work. My code is not changing my input.

**Input:**

```
Year    Lg  Winner                  Team
1956    NL  Don Newcombe (1 | MVP)  Brooklyn (1)
1957    NL  Warren Spahn (1 | HOF | ASG)    Milwaukee (1)
1958    AL  Bob Turley (1 | ASG)    New York (1)
```

**Here is how I want the output to look:**

```
Year    Lg  Winner                  Team
1956    NL  Don Newcombe            Brooklyn (1)
1957    NL  Warren Spahn            Milwaukee (1)
1958    AL  Bob Turley              New York (1)
```

**dput(dfx):**

```
structure(list(Year = 1956:1958, Lg = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("AL", 
"NL"), class = "factor"), Winner = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Bob Turley (1 | ASG)", 
"Don Newcombe (1 | MVP)", "Warren Spahn (1 | HOF | ASG)"
), class = "factor"), Team = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Brooklyn (1)", 
"Milwaukee (1)", "New York (1)"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

**Code:**

```
library(stringr)
dfnoparens <- dfx
str_replace(dfnoparens$Winner, " \\(.*\\)", "")
head(dfnoparens)
```

Comment: `m <- regexpr('^[^\\(]*', dfnoparens$Winner);regmatches(dfnoparens$Winner, m)`.

Comment: You need to assign it, i.e. `dfnoparens$Winner <-str_replace(dfnoparens$Winner, " \\(.*\\)", "")`, otherwise no need for packages, a simple `sub` would do

Comment: In Base R,   you canf use `sub("\\(.*", "", dfx$Winner)`

Comment: When I assigned it using the code below, the result did not change:
library(stringr)
dfnoparens <- dfx
dfnew <- str_replace(dfnoparens$Winner, " \\(.*\\)", "")
head(dfnew)

Comment: You have to assign it to the right place @Metsfan `dfnoparens` is just a copy of your original `dfx` try `dfnoparens$newwinner <- str_replace(dfnoparens$Winner, " \(.*\)", "")` and then `head(dfnoparens)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_extract` from the `stringr` library:

```
df$Winner <- str_extract(df$Winner, ".*(?=\\s\\(\\d)")
```

This solution uses positive lookahead in `(?=...)`; the lookahead can be glossed as "Match anything (`.*`) that occurs prior to a white space (`\\s`) followed by an opening round bracket (`\\(`) followed by a number (`\\d`)".

Result:

```
df
  Year Lg       Winner          Team
1 1956 NL Don Newcombe  Brooklyn (1)
2 1957 NL Warren Spahn Milwaukee (1)
3 1958 AL   Bob Turley  New York (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

With the test data in the question (only relevant column).

```
x <- c('Don Newcombe (1 | MVP)', 'Warren Spahn (1 | HOF | ASG)', 'Bob Turley (1 | ASG)')
```

Use `regexpr/regmatches`.

```
m <- regexpr('^[^\\(]*', x)
y <- regmatches(x, m)
y
#[1] "Don Newcombe " "Warren Spahn " "Bob Turley "
```

This output strings still have the white space before the left parenthesis, if needed remove it now.

```
trimws(y)
#[1] "Don Newcombe" "Warren Spahn" "Bob Turley"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `trimws` with `whitespace`

```
 trimws(x, whitespace = "\\s*\\(.*")
 #[1] "Don Newcombe" "Warren Spahn" "Bob Turley"
```

#### data

```
x <- c('Don Newcombe (1 | MVP)', 'Warren Spahn (1 | HOF | ASG)', 'Bob Turley (1 | ASG)')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- structure(list(Year = 1956:1958, 
                     Lg = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("AL", "NL"), class = "factor"), 
                     Winner = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), 
                                        .Label = c("Bob Turley (1 | ASG)", "Don Newcombe (1 | MVP)", 
                                                   "Warren Spahn (1 | HOF | ASG)"), class = "factor"),
                     Team = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Brooklyn (1)", "Milwaukee (1)", "New York (1)"), 
                                      class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Here is a `strsplit` solution.

```
df$Winner <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Winner)," (",fixed=TRUE), `[[`, 1))
df
  Year Lg       Winner          Team
1 1956 NL Don Newcombe  Brooklyn (1)
2 1957 NL Warren Spahn Milwaukee (1)
3 1958 AL   Bob Turley  New York (1)
```