# how to use R gsub function to remove punctuation and number?

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub

I have a column contain and I wanted to remove the (*) at the end of the string but some has space in between and some has not:

```
Variable
0. No (1)
1. Yes(2)
2. Refuse to Answer (3)
3. Agree(4)
4. Disagree (5)
```

Desired outcome:

```
Variable
0.No
1.Yes
2.Refuse to Answer
3.Agree
4.Disagree
```

I want to remove the punctuation marks (), but I left the dot and removed the number inside the blanket.

I tried to do it one by one:

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]","",df$column)
gsub("[[:num:]]","",df$column)
```

but it will also remove the front part of the string. Is there any advice? thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove parentheses and text within from strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173194/remove-parentheses-and-text-within-from-strings-in-r)

Comment: If this is the exact string format, I would just drop the last 4 characters of each string.  From memory, `stringr::str_sub(x, 1, -4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` with  `*\\(.*` to match a space 0 to n times  `*`, followed by ( `\\(` and followed by anything `.*`.
`\\. *` will match `.` followed by 0 to n space. Here also   instead of `\\. *` would give the desired result.

```
sub("\\. *", ".", sub(" *\\(.*", "", s))
#[1] "Variable"           "0.No"               "1.Yes"             
#[4] "2.Refuse to Answer" "3.Agree"            "4.Disagree"
```

Data

```
s <- c("Variable", "0. No (1)", "1. Yes(2)", "2. Refuse to Answer (3)",
  "3. Agree(4)", "4. Disagree (5)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method without `gsub`:

```
# Data (assumed data frame format, note no space for "Yes" or "Agree")
s <- data.frame(Variable = c("0. No (1)", "1. Yes(2)", "2. Refuse to Answer (3)",
       "3. Agree(4)", "4. Disagree (5)"))

# cut off last three characters, then trim whitespace
stringr::str_sub(s$Variable, 1, -4) |> stringr::str_trim()
```

gives:

```
[1] "0. No"               "1. Yes"              "2. Refuse to Answer" "3. Agree"            "4. Disagree"
```